# Foreground location service in Qt6

Tags: java, android, service, location, qt6

I want to track the location of the user non-stop. That's why I start a foreground service and use QGeoPositionInfoSource in Qt C++.

When I remove my QGeoPositionInfoSource code in Qt a notification from my foreground service comes as expected, but with the QGeoPositionInfoSource code nothing shows up ? I guess a crash happens, but I can't see what happens since it is on a seperated process !

I have tried to use QGeoPositionInfoSource::errorOccurred, but it doesn't get called. It seems the crash happens after I do source->startUpdates becuase I Have tried making  a notification after executing it and it doesn't show up, however I have a notification right before it and it shows.

I have also tried to log a notification every second that shows the time without the  QGeoPositionInfoSource code and it works just fine, so maybe I have a permisions missing here ? I have followed strictly the official android documentation for the location foreground service though - https://developer.android.com/develop/sensors-and-location/location/permissions

Here's my code

main.cpp

```cpp
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QtCore/private/qandroidextras_p.h>
#include "NotificationManager.h"
#include <QtCore/QObject>
#include <QGeoPositionInfoSource>
#include <QNetworkReply>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

#if defined(Q_OS_ANDROID)
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {
        if (argv[i])
        {
            if (QString::fromLocal8Bit(argv[i]) == "--service")
            {
                QAndroidService app(argc, argv);

                QGeoPositionInfoSource *source = QGeoPositionInfoSource::createDefaultSource(0);

                QObject::connect(source, &QGeoPositionInfoSource::errorOccurred, [](QGeoPositionInfoSource::Error positioningError)
                                 { NotificationClient::getInstance()->setNotification("Secure Me", "An error occured!"); });

                QObject::connect(source, &QGeoPositionInfoSource::positionUpdated,
                                 [&](const QGeoPositionInfo &info)
                                 {
                                     if (info.isValid())
                                     {
                                         qreal latitude = info.coordinate().latitude();
                                         qreal longitude = info.coordinate().longitude();

                                         qDebug() << "Current coordinates are:" << latitude << "," << longitude;

                                         NotificationClient::getInstance()->setNotification("Secure Test", QString::number(latitude) + " " + QString::number(longitude));
                                     }
                                 });
                NotificationClient::getInstance()->setNotification("Secure Test", "This notification works!");

                source->startUpdates();
                NotificationClient::getInstance()->setNotification("Secure Test", "This doesn't show..");
                return app.exec();
            }
        }
    }
#endif
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv, true);

#if defined(Q_OS_ANDROID)

    if (QNativeInterface::QAndroidApplication::sdkVersion() >= __ANDROID_API_T__)
    {
        QStringList permissions = {
            "android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS",
            "android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION",
            "android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"};

        for (const auto &permission : permissions)
        {
            auto requestResult = QtAndroidPrivate::requestPermission(permission);
            if (requestResult.result() != QtAndroidPrivate::Authorized)
            {
                qWarning() << "Failed to acquire permission:" << permission;
            }
        }
    }
    QJniObject::callStaticMethod<void>("tech.secureme.MyService",
                                       "startMyService",
                                       "(Landroid/content/Context;)V",
                                       QNativeInterface::QAndroidApplication::context());
#endif

    return app.exec();
}
```

MyService.java

```java
package tech.secureme;

import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationManagerCompat;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.app.Notification;

import org.qtproject.qt.android.bindings.QtService;
import android.content.pm.ServiceInfo;
import tech.secureme.utils.QGpsUtils;

public class MyService extends QtService {
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d("ServiceTest", "onStartCommand ");
        String CHANNEL_ID = "service_test";
        Intent showTaskIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyActivity.class);
        showTaskIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        showTaskIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        showTaskIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, showTaskIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mNotifyBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setTicker("Service Test")
                .setContentTitle("Service Test")
                .setContentText("Click the notification")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
                .setContentIntent(contentIntent);

        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            CharSequence name = "Service Test";
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
            NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);
            mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
        }
        startForeground(123, mNotifyBuilder.build(), ServiceInfo.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_LOCATION);
        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }

    public static void startMyService(Context ctx) {
        ctx.startService(new Intent(ctx, MyService.class));
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="tech.secureme"
    android:installLocation="auto"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true" />
    <application
        android:name="org.qtproject.qt.android.bindings.QtApplication"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:label="secureme"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:fullBackupOnly="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name="tech.secureme.MyActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|uiMode|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|layoutDirection|locale|fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|mcc|mnc|density"
            android:label="secureme"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:screenOrientation="unspecified"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="secureme" />

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.arguments"
                android:value="" />

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.extract_android_style"
                android:value="minimal" />
        </activity>

        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.qtprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/qtprovider_paths" />
        </provider>

        <receiver android:name=".BootServiceBroadcastReceiver" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:process=":qt_service" android:name=".MyService"
            android:foregroundServiceType="location">
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="-- %%INSERT_APP_LIB_NAME%% --" />
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.arguments" android:value="--service" />
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.background_running" android:value="true" />
        </service>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

EDIT:

I am not certained if in MyService.java startService function I should call startService or startForegroundService. I have just tried with startForegroundService and I get 2 huge errors.

Here they are:

```
2024-02-21 20:22:37.275 2145 9802 system E ActivityManager : ANR in tech.secureme:qt_service
PID: 8485
Reason: executing service tech.secureme/.MyService
ErrorId: 477ce99e-2119-4742-bdbe-9921f2b6e47b
Frozen: false
Load: 17.03 / 6.13 / 2.22
----- Output from /proc/pressure/memory -----
some avg10=15.09 avg60=11.29 avg300=3.40 total=11674398
full avg10=10.04 avg60=6.23 avg300=1.83 total=6517114
----- End output from /proc/pressure/memory -----

CPU usage from 0ms to 7349ms later (2024-02-21 20:22:29.680 to 2024-02-21 20:22:37.029):
  109% 2145/system_server: 58% user + 50% kernel / faults: 43918 minor 1910 major
    12% 9802/AnrConsumer: 2.4% user + 10% kernel
    9.3% 3622/binder:2145_F: 6.8% user + 2.5% kernel
    7.2% 5046/binder:2145_1B: 3.4% user + 3.8% kernel
    5.7% 2166/Signal Catcher: 2.8% user + 2.8% kernel
    5.1% 6648/binder:2145_1E: 3.4% user + 1.7% kernel
    5% 2170/HeapTaskDaemon: 3.9% user + 1% kernel
    4.4% 2221/android.bg: 0.8% user + 3.6% kernel
    4% 2396/InputDispatcher: 2.1% user + 1.9% kernel
    3.9% 2206/android.ui: 1.7% user + 2.1% kernel
    3.9% 4996/binder:2145_18: 2.7% user + 1.2% kernel
    3.2% 3510/binder:2145_E: 2% user + 1.2% kernel
    3.2% 6771/binder:2145_1F: 2% user + 1.2% kernel
    2.9% 2174/binder:2145_1: 2.1% user + 0.8% kernel
    2.9% 3939/binder:2145_15: 2% user + 0.9% kernel
    2.5% 2592/miui-gesture: 1.2% user + 1.3% kernel
    2.4% 5048/binder:2145_1C: 1.9% user + 0.5% kernel
    2% 3941/binder:2145_16: 1.2% user + 0.8% kernel
  69% 95/kswapd0: 0% user + 69% kernel
  36% 9466/com.google.android.apps.wellbeing: 16% user + 19% kernel / faults: 27137 minor 2518 major
    22% 9486/BG Thread #1: 9.3% user + 13% kernel
    3.9% 9484/BG Thread #0: 2.1% user + 1.7% kernel
    2.4% 9474/HeapTaskDaemon: 1% user + 1.3% kernel
    2.1% 9476/FinalizerDaemon: 1.2% user + 0.9% kernel
  35% 3212/com.google.android.gms.persistent: 21% user + 13% kernel / faults: 36189 minor 5157 major
    3.9% 9393/highpool[13]: 1.9% user + 2% kernel
    3.2% 5429/highpool[6]: 2.1% user + 1% kernel
    2.8% 6635/lowpool[18]: 1.9% user + 0.9% kernel
    2.8% 8241/lowpool[21]: 1.9% user + 0.9% kernel
    2.7% 3227/HeapTaskDaemon: 1.3% user + 1.3% kernel
    2.4% 3212/.gms.persistent: 1.3% user + 1% kernel
    2.1% 6120/binder:3212_9: 1.4% user + 0.6% kernel
    2% 3384/binder:3212_4: 1.3% user + 0.6% kernel
  29% 6483/com.conena.logcat.reader: 23% user + 6% kernel / faults: 24788 minor 678 major
    18% 6550/RenderThread: 15% user + 2.3% kernel
    7.5% 6483/a.logcat.reader: 5.8% user + 1.6% kernel
  18% 7382/com.google.android.tts: 15% user + 3.1% kernel / faults: 17616 minor 2243 major
    14% 7382/gle.android.tts: 12% user + 2% kernel
  13% 1189/surfaceflinger: 8% user + 5.3% kernel / faults: 4572 minor 80 major
    6.6% 1189/surfaceflinger: 5.1% user + 1.4% kernel
  9.1% 4579/com.google.android.gms: 5.4% user + 3.6% kernel / faults: 22588 minor 1271 major
  6.6% 637/lmkd: 1.2% user + 5.4% kernel / faults: 6 minor
    6.6% 637/lmkd: 1.4% user + 5.1% kernel
  6.5% 9498/com.google.android.apps.youtube.music: 3.7% user + 2.8% kernel / faults: 18079 minor 1530 major
    2.8% 9507/HeapTaskDaemon: 1.6% user + 1.2% kernel
  5.8% 632/logd: 1.4% user + 4.3% kernel / faults: 689 minor 56 major
    2.5% 647/logd.writer: 0.8% user + 1.7% kernel
  5.5% 8/kworker/u16:0-ufs_clkscaling_0: 0% user + 5.5% kernel
  5.3% 1090/vendor.qti.hardware.display.composer-service: 2.7% user + 2.5% kernel / faults: 1565 minor 116 major
    4.8% 1090/composer-servic: 2.7% user + 2.1% kernel
  4.6% 3012/com.android.systemui: 2% user + 2.5% kernel / faults: 12242 minor 1449 major
    2.1% 3012/ndroid.systemui: 1% user + 1% kernel
  4.4% 156/kworker/u16:7-ufs_clkscaling_0: 0% user + 4.4% kernel
  4.4% 587/kworker/u16:10-writeback: 0% user + 4.4% kernel
  4.3% 10/kworker/u16:1-memlat_wq: 0% user + 4.3% kernel
  4.2% 2985/com.android.phone: 1.6% user + 2.5% kernel / faults: 9051 minor 1461 major
  3.8% 147/kworker/u16:4-kgsl-lockless-work: 0% user + 3.8% kernel
```

```
2024-02-21 20:22:37.275 2145 9802 system E ActivityManager : 3.4% 1/init: 1.2% user + 2.1% kernel / faults: 619 minor 20 major
    3.2% 1/init: 1.2% user + 2% kernel
  3.4% 8485/tech.secureme:qt_service: 1.2% user + 2.1% kernel / faults: 9378 minor 2431 major
    2.4% 8497/Signal Catcher: 0.9% user + 1.5% kernel
  3.4% 9305/com.google.android.apps.tachyon: 1.3% user + 2% kernel / faults: 4286 minor 3531 major
    3% 9313/HeapTaskDaemon: 1.2% user + 1.7% kernel
  3.1% 9632/com.google.android.calendar: 1.7% user + 1.3% kernel / faults: 6365 minor 39 major
  2.9% 94/kworker/u16:2-kverityd: 0% user + 2.9% kernel
  2.8% 956/statsd: 1.4% user + 1.3% kernel / faults: 891 minor 50 major
  2.7% 449/kworker/u16:8-loop33: 0% user + 2.7% kernel
  2.7% 725/irq/213-fts_ts: 0% user + 2.7% kernel
  2.7% 4051/com.google.android.inputmethod.latin: 1.4% user + 1.2% kernel / faults: 6072 minor 253 major
    2.1% 4059/Signal Catcher: 1.3% user + 0.8% kernel
  2.3% 154/kworker/u16:5-kverityd: 0% user + 2.3% kernel
  2.3% 9118/com.google.android.apps.photos: 1% user + 1.2% kernel / faults: 7798 minor 44 major
  1.9% 1129/media.hwcodec: 0.6% user + 1.2% kernel / faults: 2521 minor 77 major
  1.9% 1736/qcrilNrd: 0.9% user + 0.9% kernel / faults: 1125 minor 390 major
  1.7% 8854/com.google.android.projection.gearhead:car: 0.9% user + 0.8% kernel / faults: 3967 minor 908 major
  1.7% 9416/com.google.android.apps.turbo:aab: 1% user + 0.6% kernel / faults: 6930 minor 307 major
  1.6% 120/kworker/u16:3-ufs_clkscaling_0: 0% user + 1.6% kernel
  1.6% 1577/media.swcodec: 0.6% user + 0.9% kernel / faults: 3164 minor 72 major
  1.4% 1060/android.hardware.wifi@1.0-service: 0.6% user + 0.8% kernel / faults: 613 minor 188 major
  1.4% 2825/com.android.bluetooth: 0.2% user + 1.2% kernel / faults: 2413 minor 584 major
  1.5% 5166/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search: 0.1% user + 1.3% kernel / faults: 2453 minor 1016 major
  1.5% 8270/tech.secureme: 0.4% user + 1% kernel / faults: 3177 minor 1171 major
  1.5% 8642/com.instagram.android: 0.1% user + 1.3% kernel / faults: 2405 minor 192 major
  1.3% 14/rcu_preempt: 0% user + 1.3% kernel
  1.3% 1130/media.audio.qc.codec: 0.5% user + 0.8% kernel / faults: 1913 minor 57 major
  1.3% 4949/com.android.nfc: 0.5% user + 0.8% kernel / faults: 3784 minor 206 major
  1.3% 9781/com.google.android.cellbroadcastreceiver: 0.6% user + 0.6% kernel / faults: 3031 minor 21 major
  1.2% 1112/vendor.qti.hardware.perf-hal-service: 0.5% user + 0.6% kernel / faults: 1288 minor 23 major
  1.2% 1555/media.codec: 0.6% user + 0.5% kernel / faults: 1710 minor 51 major
  1.2% 4930/com.miui.daemon: 0.5% user + 0.6% kernel / faults: 4331 minor 501 major
  1.2% 5084/com.xiaomi.NetworkBoost: 0.5% user + 0.6% kernel / faults: 4904 minor 338 major
  1.2% 5447/android.process.acore: 0.4% user + 0.8% kernel / faults: 2239 minor 497 major
  1.2% 9446/com.google.android.apps.turbo:ssb: 0.4% user + 0.8% kernel / faults: 6400 minor 8 major
  1% 675/crtc_commit:82: 0% user + 1% kernel
  1% 7744/logcat: 0.6% user + 0.4% kernel / faults: 134 minor
  1% 8976/logcat: 0.5% user + 0.5% kernel / faults: 162 minor
  0.9% 51/rcuog/4: 0% user + 0.9% kernel
  0% 86/kcompactd0: 0% user + 0% kernel
  0.9% 1512/cameraserver: 0.1% user + 0.8% kernel / faults: 388 minor 93 major
  0.9% 1535/media.extractor: 0.2% user + 0.6% kernel / faults: 1327 minor 45 major
  0.8% 15/rcuog/0: 0% user + 0.8% kernel
  0.8% 52/rcuop/4: 0% user + 0.8% kernel
  0.8% 2272/cds_ol_rx_threa: 0% user + 0.8% kernel
  0.8% 7212/kworker/0:2H-kblockd: 0% user + 0.8% kernel
  0.8% 8450/com.android.statementservice: 0.2% user + 0.5% kernel / faults: 2070 minor 622 major
  0.6% 678/kgsl_dispatcher: 0% user + 0.6% kernel
  0% 808/tombstoned: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 188 minor 63 major
  0.6% 1177/audioserver: 0.1% user + 0.5% kernel / faults: 377 minor 34 major
  0.6% 5347/com.google.process.gservices: 0.4% user + 0.2% kernel / faults: 1551 minor 63 major
  0.5% 66/rcuop/6: 0% user + 0.5% kernel
```

I also have several warning after them:
[image]

Why is that ? What should I do ? Could someone please help me out here?

Comment: Move `QGuiApplication app(argc, argv, true);` before for-loop

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. I have just tried that and it doesn't change anything. I have edited the post with a couple of things I have tried and I am not sure about. Could you please review it after the EDIT: text ?